# Рэкетир и рэкитер

Tags: орфография, заимствования

Об этом говорилось в одном из ответов, но хотелось бы уточнить. Как все-таки правильно: И или Ё? Ведь аналогичные слова "волонтер", "гренадер" пишутся через Ё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно И. Может, потому что в английском звучит И?
РЭКЕТИ́Р [не: рэкетёр], а, м., одуш. [англ. **racketeer**].Преступник, занимающийся рэкетом.Рэкети́рский —относящийся к рэкетиру, рэкетирам.
Яндекс.Словари › Словарь иноязычных слов, 2004

Гренадер, волонтёр - из французского  volontaire < volonté воля, желание; grenadier < grenade граната].